# It seems to me that my UIWebView is behind other views

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, view

I am adding a new uiwebview in order to login.
One day(After updating to iOS9, but I think that this is not the reason) I failed to show this uiwebview.
So, what can I do to be sure, that my view is at the top ?
Is there any way to programmatically get it higher ?

Comment: if it's the last view to be added to the viewcontroller's root view, then it should be on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView * _Nonnull)view

Use this on the superview of your UIWebView:
eg:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.webView];
```